# Related reference value not showing up on list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

I have been struggling with this problem for much too long and am hoping that one of you will be able to see what I cannot.   It has to be a simple stupid error since I do this everywhere in the application with no errors.

Problem:   I have a billing_type (reference) table which contains a number of records.   I also have a billing table which contains bills.   When I display the billing table in a list, the billing_type is show as:

```
   "#<BillingType:0x00000006f49470>"
```

which I am assuming is its pointer.

The billing_type model :

```
   class BillingType < ActiveRecord::Base
      validates :billing_type, presence: true, uniqueness: true
      has_many :billings
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :billings
   end
```

The billing model :

```
   class Billing < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :billing_type
      belongs_to :horse
      validates :billing_type_id, presence: true  
      validates :horse_id, presence: true
   end
```

The schema:

```
   create_table "billing_types", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.string   "billing_type"
      t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
   end

   add_index "billing_types", ["billing_type"], name: "index_billing_types_on_billing_type", unique: true

   create_table "billings", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.date     "billing_date"
      t.integer  "billing_type_id"
      t.integer  "horse_id"
      t.string   "notes"
      t.decimal  "cost"
      t.date     "date_billed"
      t.date     "date_received"
      t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
   end
```

The query in the controller (note:  I exported the database and put this in the SQL and it returned everything, including the billing_type, o.k.):

```
   def index
      @billings = Billing.find_by_sql("SELECT billings.id, billings.billing_date, horses.horse_name, billings.billing_type_id, billing_types.billing_type, billings.notes, billings.cost, billings.date_billed, billings.date_received FROM billings JOIN horses ON billings.horse_id = horses.id JOIN billing_types ON billings.billing_type_id = billing_types.id ORDER BY billings.billing_date, LOWER(horses.horse_name)")
   end
```

The index page:
.
.
.

```
   <div class = "table-container">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
         <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Billing date</th>
            <th>Horse name</th>
            <th>Billing type</th>
```

.
.
.

```
            </tr>
         </thead>

         <tbody>
            <% @billings.each do |billing| %>
                <tr>
                <% if billing.billing_date %>
                   <td><%= billing.billing_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %></td>
                <% else %>
                   <td><%= billing.billing_date %></td>
                <% end %>
                <td><%= billing.horse_name %></td>
                <td><%= billing.billing_type %></td>
```

.
.
.

```
               </tr>
            <% end %>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Thanking you in advance for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what I would expect to see

billing.billing_type is the representation of the the whole BillingType class as an object.

If you wanted that then maybe

`billing.billing_type.inspect` is what you are expecting but I suspect that what you really want is the name in which case you should be looking to display a property of the object not the object itself. i.e.

`billing.billing_type.name`

Comment: Ahh!   Didn't think of that.   I think I will just change the name from billing_type to something else like billing_type_name to avoid confusion.  Thanks very much.   I am pretty convinced you are right, but will check it out first and then return and give you a tick.

Comment: Thanks again.   That did fix it.